# Join in SparkSQL to design a JSON

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am taking the tables from SQL Server and processing, transforming into JSON file in Spark application and after that I am  storing into MongoDB. I have exported a JSON file, in this JSON file `ACCOUNTNO` is unique, one `ACCOUNTNO` might have one or multiple `VEHICLENUMBER`, so I have created an array for unique `ACCOUNTNO`. we have put multiple `VEHICLENUMBER` in seperate objects inside the `VEHICLE` array.

I have used this query:

```
val res00 = sparksessionobject.sqlContext.sql(SELECT ACCOUNTNO, collect_set(struct(VEHICLENUMBER, CUSTOMERID,ACCOUNTGROUPID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE,SOURCEOFENTRY,REVENUECATEGORYID,VEHICLECLASS,SERIALNO,HEXTAGID,TAGSTATUS,TAGSTARTEFFDATE,TAGENDEFFDATE,ISTAGBLACKLISTED,ISBLACKLISTHOLD,RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS,EMAILADDRESS,PHONENUMBER,CREATEDDATE,CREATEDUSER,UPDATEDDATE,UPDATEDUSER,ISFEEWAIVER,FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE,VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS,TAGTID,ISREVENUERECHARGE)) as VEHICLE FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY VEHICLENUMBER ORDER BY TAGSTARTEFFDATE DESC) AS rn FROM tp_customer_account) tmp WHERE rn=1 GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO")
res00.coalesce(1).write.json("D:/res39")
```

I got the JSON file looks like this.

```
ACCOUNTNO    :    10003018
VEHICLE    :    Array
                0    :    Object

ACCOUNTNO    :    10003019
VEHICLE    :    Array
                0    :    Object
                1    :    Object
                2    :    Object

ACCOUNTNO    :    10003020
             VEHICLE    :    Array
             0    :    Object
                VEHICLENUMBER    :    "MH01AX5658"
                CUSTOMERID    :    20000006
                ACCOUNTGROUPID    :    21
                PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID    :    3079
                PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE    :    2015-09-16 14:58:27.593
                SOURCEOFENTRY    :    "RegularRetailer"
                REVENUECATEGORYID    :    75
                VEHICLECLASS    :    "4"
                SERIALNO    :    "137438955930"
                HEXTAGID    :    "9189070480200000099A"
                TAGSTATUS    :    "TAGINACTIVE"
                TAGSTARTEFFDATE    :    2013-06-16 12:27:34.997
                TAGENDEFFDATE    :    2015-09-16 15:21:39.960
                ISTAGBLACKLISTED    :    true
                ISBLACKLISTHOLD    :    false
                EMAILADDRESS    :    "prabjyotsingh.kalsi@yahoo.com ..."
                PHONENUMBER    :    "09909913811 "
                CREATEDDATE    :    2013-06-16 12:12:37.327
                CREATEDUSER    :    "bhagwadapos"
                UPDATEDDATE    :    2015-09-16 15:06:39.960
                UPDATEDUSER    :    "BLTagProcess"
```

Another view of the same JSON file using `pretty()` in MongoDB database.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5ac17b0fef3110a8eb2319"),
        "ACCOUNTNO" : NumberLong(10003014),
        "VEHICLE" : [
                {
                        "VEHICLENUMBER" : "MH43AJ411",
                        "CUSTOMERID" : NumberLong(20000001),
                        "ACCOUNTGROUPID" : 15,
                        "PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID" : 3079,
                        "PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE" : ISODate("2015-09-16T09:28:27.500Z"),
                        "SOURCEOFENTRY" : "RegularRetailer",
                        "REVENUECATEGORYID" : 75,
                        "VEHICLECLASS" : "4",
                        "SERIALNO" : "206158433290",
                        "HEXTAGID" : "91890704803000000C0A",
                        "TAGSTATUS" : "TAGINACTIVE",
                        "TAGSTARTEFFDATE" : ISODate("2014-08-08T08:54:12.227Z"),
                        "TAGENDEFFDATE" : ISODate("2015-09-16T09:51:42.437Z"),
                        "ISTAGBLACKLISTED" : true,
                        "ISBLACKLISTHOLD" : false,
                        "EMAILADDRESS" : "shankarn75@rediffmail.com                                                                                                                                                                                     ",
                        "PHONENUMBER" : "9004419178     ",
                        "CREATEDDATE" : ISODate("2013-06-07T07:26:16.650Z"),
                        "CREATEDUSER" : "bhagwadapos",
                        "UPDATEDDATE" : ISODate("2015-09-16T09:36:42.437Z"),
                        "UPDATEDUSER" : "BLTagProcess"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5ac17b0fef3110a8eb231a"),
        "ACCOUNTNO" : NumberLong(10003015),
        "VEHICLE" : [
                {
                        "VEHICLENUMBER" : "MH12GZ3392",
                        "CUSTOMERID" : NumberLong(20000002),
                        "ACCOUNTGROUPID" : 16,
                        "PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID" : 2079,
                        "PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE" : ISODate("2013-06-07T07:44:13.903Z"),
                        "SOURCEOFENTRY" : "RegularRetailer",
                        "REVENUECATEGORYID" : 75,
                        "VEHICLECLASS" : "4",
                        "SERIALNO" : "137438955875",
                        "HEXTAGID" : "91890704802000000963",
                        "TAGSTATUS" : "Assigned",
                        "TAGSTARTEFFDATE" : ISODate("2013-06-07T07:47:11.550Z"),
                        "TAGENDEFFDATE" : ISODate("2018-06-06T18:29:59.997Z"),
                        "ISTAGBLACKLISTED" : false,
                        "ISBLACKLISTHOLD" : false,
                        "EMAILADDRESS" : "hiteshmpatil@gmail.com                                                                                                                                                                                        ",
                        "PHONENUMBER" : "9823131243     ",
                        "CREATEDDATE" : ISODate("2013-06-07T07:45:29.337Z"),
                        "CREATEDUSER" : "bhagwadapos",
                        "UPDATEDDATE" : ISODate("2013-06-07T07:45:29.337Z"),
                        "UPDATEDUSER" : "bhagwadapos"
                }
        ]
}
```

So I have 3 more tables in that SQL Server like Email table, Login table and phones table. Each table contains `ACCOUNTNO`.

All the 3 tables contains `ACCOUNTNO`, so I have to insert the same `ACCOUNTNO` rows contains in the each of the 3 tables into the single JSON file

So the requirement is I want to add 3 more array after `ACCOUNTNO` and before `VEHICLENO` in the JSON file and it should be look like this probably which is given below

```
ACCOUNTNO    :    10003018
Email      :    Array
                0    :    Object
Login      :    Array
                0    :    Object
Phones    :    Array
                0    :    Object
VEHICLE    :    Array
                0    :    Object
```

**`TP_CUSTOMER_LOGINS` table view of the columns and one row value:**

```
LOGINID ACCOUNTNO   USERNAME    PASSWORD    LAST_LOGINDATE  LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE   CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE  PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT  PINNUMBER   ISLOCKED    CREATEDDATE CREATEDUSER UPDATEDDATE UPDATEDUSER THEMES  LANGUAGES   STATUSID    USERTYPEID  ROLENAME    SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT SQ_LOCKOUTTIME
        41118   10076338    user1212    passpasspasspass    27:23.2 20:29.0 20:12.8 0       0   20:29.0 deenkapoor  27:39.5 deenkapoor  Maroon  en-IN   2111    2       NULL    NULL
```

**`TP_CUSTOMER_EMAILS` table view of the columns and one row value:**

```
CUSTMAILID  ACCOUNTNO   EMAILTYPE   EMAILADDRESS    ISACTIVE    ISCOMMUNICATION CREATEDDATE CREATEDUSER UPDATEDDATE UPDATEDUSER
38404   10078435    PrimaryEmail    something.ok@gmail.com  1   1   26:36.3 System  26:36.3 System
```

**`TP_CUSTOMER_PHONES`  table view of the columns and one row value:**

```
CUSTPHONEID ACCOUNTNO   PHONETYPE   PHONENUMBER EXTENTION   ISACTIVE    ISCOMMUNICATION CREATEDDATE CREATEDUSER UPDATEDDATE UPDATEDUSER
91831   10078435    MobileNo    9999999999      1   1   26:36.3 System  26:36.3 System
```

## I have to join in the SparkSQL query. Need help. Thanks.

> Updated!
>   I have tried to join using 2 tables first, I have written the SQL Query which is working in SQL Server, but it is not working in SparkSQL

Code:

```
package com.issuer.pack3.spark

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object sqltojson {

  def main(args:Array[String])
    {
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:/winutil/")

      val db = "ISSUER"
      val table1 = "[HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS]"
      val custinfo1 = "[PLAY].TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES"


      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SQLtoJSON").setMaster("local[*]")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
      import sqlContext.implicits._

      val jdbcSqlConnStr = s"jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.70.15;databaseName=$db;user=bhaskar;password=welcome123;"      
      val jdbcDbTable1 = table1
      val jdbcDbTable2 = custinfo1
      val jdbcDF1 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> jdbcSqlConnStr,"dbtable" -> jdbcDbTable1)).load()
      val jdbcDF2 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> jdbcSqlConnStr,"dbtable" -> jdbcDbTable2)).load()
    //jdbcDF.show(10)
    //jdbcDF.printSchema


     jdbcDF1.registerTempTable("customer_account")
     jdbcDF2.registerTempTable("customer_address")
     val query1 = "WITH RowNumberedAccounts AS( select  O.CUSTADDRESSID ,O.ADDRESSTYPE ,O.ADDRESSLINE1 ,O.ADDRESSLINE2 ,O.ADDRESSLINE3 ,O.CITY,O.STATE  ,O.COUNTRY  ,O.ZIP1  ,O.ISACTIVE  ,O.ISCOMMUNICATION  ,O.CREATEDDATE  ,O.CREATEDUSER  ,O.UPDATEDDATE  ,O.UPDATEDUSER  ,O.REASONCODE ,O.ZIP2 ,C.ACCOUNTNO         as C_ACCNO        ,C.CUSTOMERID        ,C.ACCOUNTGROUPID        ,C.PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID        ,C.PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE        ,C.SOURCEOFENTRY        ,C.REVENUECATEGORYID        ,C.VEHICLENUMBER        ,C.VEHICLECLASS        ,C.SERIALNO        ,C.HEXTAGID        ,C.TAGSTATUS        ,C.TAGSTARTEFFDATE        ,C.TAGENDEFFDATE        ,C.ISTAGBLACKLISTED        ,C.ISBLACKLISTHOLD        ,C.RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS        ,C.EMAILADDRESS        ,C.PHONENUMBER        ,C.CREATEDDATE AS CCreatedDate  ,C.CREATEDUSER AS CCreatedUser        ,C.UPDATEDDATE AS CUpdatedDate        ,C.UPDATEDUSER AS CUpdatedUser        ,C.HISTID        ,C.ACTION        ,C.ISFEEWAIVER        ,C.FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE        ,C.VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS        ,C.TAGTID        ,C.ISREVENUERECHARGE        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (            PARTITION BY C.VEHICLENUMBER            ORDER BY C.TAGSTARTEFFDATE DESC) AS rn    from        customer_account c        INNER join customer_address o on c.ACCOUNTNO = o.ACCOUNTNO)SELECT    R.* FROM    RowNumberedAccounts AS R WHERE    rn = 1 order by C_ACCNO"
     val res00 = sqlContext.sql(query1.toString) 
     res00.registerTempTable("joined_acc_add")
     res00.show(10)
     val query2 = "SELECT C_ACCNO AS ACCOUNTNO, collect_set(struct(VEHICLENUMBER, CUSTOMERID,ACCOUNTGROUPID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE,SOURCEOFENTRY,REVENUECATEGORYID,VEHICLECLASS,SERIALNO,HEXTAGID,TAGSTATUS,TAGSTARTEFFDATE,TAGENDEFFDATE,ISTAGBLACKLISTED,ISBLACKLISTHOLD,RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS,EMAILADDRESS,PHONENUMBER,CREATEDDATE,CREATEDUSER,UPDATEDDATE,UPDATEDUSER,ISFEEWAIVER,FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE,VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS,TAGTID,ISREVENUERECHARGE)) as VEHICLE, collect_set(struct(CUSTADDRESSID ,ADDRESSTYPE ,ADDRESSLINE1 ,ADDRESSLINE2 ,ADDRESSLINE3 ,CITY,O.STATE  ,COUNTRY  ,ZIP1  ,ISACTIVE  ,ISCOMMUNICATION  ,CREATEDDATE  ,CREATEDUSER  ,UPDATEDDATE  ,UPDATEDUSER  ,REASONCODE ,ZIP2)) as ADDRESS FROM joined_acc_add GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO"
     val res01 = sqlContext.sql(query2.toString)
     res01.coalesce(1).write.json("D:/result01")







//###########################
//  jdbcDF.withColumn("VEHICLE",struct("VEHICLENUMBER","CUSTOMERID")) // withColumn for Add or replace Columns, struct for Creates a new struct column.
//  .select("VEHICLE","ACCOUNTNO")
//  .groupBy("ACCOUNTNO")
//  .agg(collect_set("VEHICLE").as("VEHICLE")). //collect_set(Column e) It's an Aggregate function: returns a set of objects with duplicate elements eliminated.
//  orderBy("ACCOUNTNO").
//  coalesce(1).write.json("D:/res10")


    }
  }
```

Error StackTrace:

```
18/08/07 13:31:25 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: show at sqltojson.scala:40, took 99.958582 s
18/08/07 13:31:25 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 11.907295 ms
18/08/07 13:31:25 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: SELECT C_ACCNO AS ACCOUNTNO, collect_set(struct(VEHICLENUMBER, CUSTOMERID,ACCOUNTGROUPID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE,SOURCEOFENTRY,REVENUECATEGORYID,VEHICLECLASS,SERIALNO,HEXTAGID,TAGSTATUS,TAGSTARTEFFDATE,TAGENDEFFDATE,ISTAGBLACKLISTED,ISBLACKLISTHOLD,RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS,EMAILADDRESS,PHONENUMBER,CREATEDDATE,CREATEDUSER,UPDATEDDATE,UPDATEDUSER,ISFEEWAIVER,FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE,VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS,TAGTID,ISREVENUERECHARGE)) as VEHICLE, collect_set(struct(CUSTADDRESSID ,ADDRESSTYPE ,ADDRESSLINE1 ,ADDRESSLINE2 ,ADDRESSLINE3 ,CITY,O.STATE  ,COUNTRY  ,ZIP1  ,ISACTIVE  ,ISCOMMUNICATION  ,CREATEDDATE  ,CREATEDUSER  ,UPDATEDDATE  ,UPDATEDUSER  ,REASONCODE ,ZIP2)) as ADDRESS FROM joined_acc_add GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO
+-------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+-----+-------+------+--------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+----------+----+--------+----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-------+------+-----------+-----------------+----------------------------+------+-----------------+---+
|CUSTADDRESSID|ADDRESSTYPE|        ADDRESSLINE1|        ADDRESSLINE2|ADDRESSLINE3|       CITY|STATE|COUNTRY|  ZIP1|ISACTIVE|ISCOMMUNICATION|         CREATEDDATE|CREATEDUSER|         UPDATEDDATE|UPDATEDUSER|REASONCODE|ZIP2| C_ACCNO|CUSTOMERID|ACCOUNTGROUPID|PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID|PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE|  SOURCEOFENTRY|REVENUECATEGORYID|VEHICLENUMBER|VEHICLECLASS|    SERIALNO|            HEXTAGID|      TAGSTATUS|     TAGSTARTEFFDATE|       TAGENDEFFDATE|ISTAGBLACKLISTED|ISBLACKLISTHOLD|RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS|        EMAILADDRESS|    PHONENUMBER|        CCreatedDate|CCreatedUser|        CUpdatedDate|CUpdatedUser| HISTID|ACTION|ISFEEWAIVER|FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE|VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS|TAGTID|ISREVENUERECHARGE| rn|
+-------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+-----+-------+------+--------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+----------+----+--------+----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-------+------+-----------+-----------------+----------------------------+------+-----------------+---+
|           41|    Mailing|B309 PROGRESSIVE ...|            SECTOR-6|    GHANSOLI|NAVI MUMBAI|   MH|    IND|400701|    true|           true|2013-06-07 12:55:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-07 12:55:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003014|  20000001|            15|                  3079|    2015-09-16 14:58:...|RegularRetailer|               75|    MH43AJ411|           4|206158433290|91890704803000000C0A|    TAGINACTIVE|2014-08-08 14:24:...|2015-09-16 15:21:...|            true|          false|                null|shankarn75@rediff...|9004419178     |2013-06-07 12:56:...| bhagwadapos|2015-09-16 15:06:...|BLTagProcess|  16257|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           86|    Mailing|FLAT NO 11 TANUSH...|           SAI CHOWK|            |       PUNE|   MH|    IND|411027|    true|           true|2013-06-07 13:11:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-07 13:11:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003015|  20000002|            16|                  2079|    2013-06-07 13:14:...|RegularRetailer|               75|   MH12GZ3392|           4|137438955875|91890704802000000963|       Assigned|2013-06-07 13:17:...|2018-06-06 23:59:...|           false|          false|                null|hiteshmpatil@gmai...|9823131243     |2013-06-07 13:15:...| bhagwadapos|2013-06-07 13:15:...| bhagwadapos|      3|INSERT|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           42|    Mailing|at-susmma  sadan ...|kotak  vallay  pa...|            |     valsad|   GJ|    IND|396001|    true|           true|2013-06-07 14:28:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-07 14:28:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003016|  20000003|            17|                  2131|    2014-11-24 02:30:...|RegularRetailer|               75|    GJ15Z8173|           9|137438955877|91890704802000000965|    TAGINACTIVE|2013-06-07 14:46:...|2014-11-24 02:52:...|            true|          false|                null|bhagwada.irb@gmai...|8652836666     |2013-06-07 14:31:...| bhagwadapos|2014-11-24 02:37:...|BLTagProcess|   7747|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           43|    Mailing|Flat No 1, Buildi...|    Near Shivaji Pak|            |      Dadar|   MH|    IND|400002|    true|           true|2013-06-13 12:48:...| charotipos|2013-06-13 12:48:...| charotipos|      null|null|10003018|  20000004|            19|                  2131|    2014-11-24 02:30:...|RegularRetailer|               75|    MH05AM902|          11|137438955473|918907048020000007D1|    TAGINACTIVE|2013-06-13 13:15:...|2014-11-24 02:51:...|            true|          false|                null|kelkar.suhas@gmai...|9821032045     |2013-06-13 12:50:...|  charotipos|2014-11-24 02:36:...|BLTagProcess|   7700|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           87|    Mailing|DESAICONSTRUCTION...|OPP NEW GIDC NH08...|            |     VALSAD|   GJ|    IND|396035|    true|           true|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003019|  20009020|            20|                  2079|    2016-05-25 18:22:...|       Internal|               75|   GJ15CF7747|           4| 68719486473|91890704801000002609|       ASSIGNED|2016-05-25 18:46:...| 2041-05-25 23:59:59|           false|           null|                2083|kaviwala@desaicon...|9879110770     |2016-05-25 18:22:...|      263858|2017-02-27 11:35:...|     HUSSAIN|2064466|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           87|    Mailing|DESAICONSTRUCTION...|OPP NEW GIDC NH08...|            |     VALSAD|   GJ|    IND|396035|    true|           true|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003019|  20000008|            20|                  2129|    2016-02-16 02:40:...|RegularRetailer|               75|    GJ15CB727|           4|137438955936|918907048020000009A0|RETURNEDDAMAGED|2013-06-17 12:36:...|2016-02-08 17:12:...|            true|          false|                null|kaviwala@desaicon...|9879110770     |2013-06-17 12:26:...| bhagwadapos|2016-02-16 02:46:...|BatchProcess|  29254|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           87|    Mailing|DESAICONSTRUCTION...|OPP NEW GIDC NH08...|            |     VALSAD|   GJ|    IND|396035|    true|           true|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003019|  20001223|            20|                  2079|    2014-06-06 14:52:...|       AgentPOS|               75|   GJ15CA7837|           4|137438956220|91890704802000000ABC|       ASSIGNED|2014-06-06 14:57:...| 2039-06-06 23:59:59|           false|           null|                2083|kaviwala@desaicon...|9879110770     |2014-06-06 15:00:...| bhagwadapos|2017-02-27 11:35:...|     HUSSAIN|2064457|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           87|    Mailing|DESAICONSTRUCTION...|OPP NEW GIDC NH08...|            |     VALSAD|   GJ|    IND|396035|    true|           true|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003019|  20029961|            20|                  2079|    2016-07-28 16:27:...|       Internal|               75|   GJ15CD7387|           4| 68719511515|918907048010000087DB|       ASSIGNED|2016-07-28 19:21:...| 2041-07-28 23:59:59|           false|           null|                2083|kaviwala@desaicon...|9879110770     |2016-07-28 16:27:...|      280603|2017-02-07 17:24:...|     HUSSAIN|1607128|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           87|    Mailing|DESAICONSTRUCTION...|OPP NEW GIDC NH08...|            |     VALSAD|   GJ|    IND|396035|    true|           true|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003019|  20001557|            20|                  2079|    2014-10-01 18:22:...|       Internal|               75|   GJ15CB9601|           4| 68719479744|91890704801000000BC0|       ASSIGNED|2016-05-05 16:45:...| 2041-05-05 23:59:59|           false|           null|                2083|kaviwala@desaicon...|9879110770     |2014-10-01 18:33:...|      263858|2017-02-27 11:35:...|     HUSSAIN|2064460|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
|           87|    Mailing|DESAICONSTRUCTION...|OPP NEW GIDC NH08...|            |     VALSAD|   GJ|    IND|396035|    true|           true|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|2013-06-15 11:18:...|bhagwadapos|      null|null|10003019|  20000933|            20|                  2079|    2014-02-12 13:52:...|RegularRetailer|               75|   MH02DG7774|           4|137438956174|91890704802000000A8E|       Assigned|2014-02-12 13:49:...|2019-02-11 23:59:...|           false|          false|                null|kaviwala@desaicon...|9879110770     |2014-02-12 13:43:...| bhagwadapos|2017-02-27 11:35:...|     HUSSAIN|2064453|UPDATE|       null|             null|                        null|  null|             null|  1|
+-------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+-----+-------+------+--------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+----------+----+--------+----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-------+------+-----------+-----------------+----------------------------+------+-----------------+---+
only showing top 10 rows

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`ACCOUNTNO`' given input columns: [REASONCODE, EMAILADDRESS, ADDRESSTYPE, VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS, CUpdatedUser, ISBLACKLISTHOLD, TAGENDEFFDATE, ZIP2, VEHICLENUMBER, ISFEEWAIVER, ZIP1, FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE, UPDATEDUSER, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID, C_ACCNO, PHONENUMBER, ISACTIVE, SERIALNO, ACTION, CREATEDUSER, rn, ADDRESSLINE2, HISTID, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE, TAGTID, CCreatedDate, ADDRESSLINE3, CUpdatedDate, ISCOMMUNICATION, ADDRESSLINE1, ACCOUNTGROUPID, CITY, COUNTRY, CUSTADDRESSID, CREATEDDATE, CUSTOMERID, VEHICLECLASS, TAGSTARTEFFDATE, REVENUECATEGORYID, CCreatedUser, ISTAGBLACKLISTED, RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS, STATE, HEXTAGID, ISREVENUERECHARGE, UPDATEDDATE, SOURCEOFENTRY, TAGSTATUS]; line 1 pos 730;
'Sort ['ACCOUNTNO ASC NULLS FIRST], true
+- 'Aggregate ['ACCOUNTNO], [C_ACCNO#100L AS ACCOUNTNO#207L, collect_set(named_struct(VEHICLENUMBER, VEHICLENUMBER#7, CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMERID#0L, ACCOUNTGROUPID, ACCOUNTGROUPID#2, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID#3, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE#4, SOURCEOFENTRY, SOURCEOFENTRY#5, REVENUECATEGORYID, REVENUECATEGORYID#6, VEHICLECLASS, VEHICLECLASS#8, SERIALNO, SERIALNO#9, HEXTAGID, HEXTAGID#10, TAGSTATUS, TAGSTATUS#11, TAGSTARTEFFDATE, TAGSTARTEFFDATE#12, ... 30 more fields), 0, 0) AS VEHICLE#208, 'collect_set(named_struct(CUSTADDRESSID, CUSTADDRESSID#61L, ADDRESSTYPE, ADDRESSTYPE#63, ADDRESSLINE1, ADDRESSLINE1#64, ADDRESSLINE2, ADDRESSLINE2#65, ADDRESSLINE3, ADDRESSLINE3#66, CITY, CITY#67, NamePlaceholder, 'O.STATE, COUNTRY, COUNTRY#69, ZIP1, ZIP1#70, ISACTIVE, ISACTIVE#71, ISCOMMUNICATION, ISCOMMUNICATION#72, CREATEDDATE, CREATEDDATE#73, ... 10 more fields)) AS ADDRESS#209]
   +- SubqueryAlias joined_acc_add
      +- Sort [C_ACCNO#100L ASC NULLS FIRST], true
         +- Project [CUSTADDRESSID#61L, ADDRESSTYPE#63, ADDRESSLINE1#64, ADDRESSLINE2#65, ADDRESSLINE3#66, CITY#67, STATE#68, COUNTRY#69, ZIP1#70, ISACTIVE#71, ISCOMMUNICATION#72, CREATEDDATE#73, CREATEDUSER#74, UPDATEDDATE#75, UPDATEDUSER#76, REASONCODE#77, ZIP2#78, C_ACCNO#100L, CUSTOMERID#0L, ACCOUNTGROUPID#2, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID#3, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE#4, SOURCEOFENTRY#5, REVENUECATEGORYID#6, ... 24 more fields]
            +- Filter (rn#105 = 1)
               +- SubqueryAlias R
                  +- SubqueryAlias RowNumberedAccounts
                     +- Project [CUSTADDRESSID#61L, ADDRESSTYPE#63, ADDRESSLINE1#64, ADDRESSLINE2#65, ADDRESSLINE3#66, CITY#67, STATE#68, COUNTRY#69, ZIP1#70, ISACTIVE#71, ISCOMMUNICATION#72, CREATEDDATE#73, CREATEDUSER#74, UPDATEDDATE#75, UPDATEDUSER#76, REASONCODE#77, ZIP2#78, C_ACCNO#100L, CUSTOMERID#0L, ACCOUNTGROUPID#2, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID#3, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE#4, SOURCEOFENTRY#5, REVENUECATEGORYID#6, ... 24 more fields]
                        +- Project [CUSTADDRESSID#61L, ADDRESSTYPE#63, ADDRESSLINE1#64, ADDRESSLINE2#65, ADDRESSLINE3#66, CITY#67, STATE#68, COUNTRY#69, ZIP1#70, ISACTIVE#71, ISCOMMUNICATION#72, CREATEDDATE#73, CREATEDUSER#74, UPDATEDDATE#75, UPDATEDUSER#76, REASONCODE#77, ZIP2#78, C_ACCNO#100L, CUSTOMERID#0L, ACCOUNTGROUPID#2, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID#3, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE#4, SOURCEOFENTRY#5, REVENUECATEGORYID#6, ... 25 more fields]
                           +- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(VEHICLENUMBER#7, TAGSTARTEFFDATE#12 DESC NULLS LAST, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rn#105], [VEHICLENUMBER#7], [TAGSTARTEFFDATE#12 DESC NULLS LAST]
                              +- Project [CUSTADDRESSID#61L, ADDRESSTYPE#63, ADDRESSLINE1#64, ADDRESSLINE2#65, ADDRESSLINE3#66, CITY#67, STATE#68, COUNTRY#69, ZIP1#70, ISACTIVE#71, ISCOMMUNICATION#72, CREATEDDATE#73, CREATEDUSER#74, UPDATEDDATE#75, UPDATEDUSER#76, REASONCODE#77, ZIP2#78, ACCOUNTNO#1L AS C_ACCNO#100L, CUSTOMERID#0L, ACCOUNTGROUPID#2, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID#3, PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE#4, SOURCEOFENTRY#5, REVENUECATEGORYID#6, ... 23 more fields]
                                 +- Join Inner, (ACCOUNTNO#1L = ACCOUNTNO#62L)
                                    :- SubqueryAlias c
                                    :  +- SubqueryAlias customer_account
                                    :     +- Relation[CUSTOMERID#0L,ACCOUNTNO#1L,ACCOUNTGROUPID#2,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID#3,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE#4,SOURCEOFENTRY#5,REVENUECATEGORYID#6,VEHICLENUMBER#7,VEHICLECLASS#8,SERIALNO#9,HEXTAGID#10,TAGSTATUS#11,TAGSTARTEFFDATE#12,TAGENDEFFDATE#13,ISTAGBLACKLISTED#14,ISBLACKLISTHOLD#15,RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS#16,EMAILADDRESS#17,PHONENUMBER#18,CREATEDDATE#19,CREATEDUSER#20,UPDATEDDATE#21,UPDATEDUSER#22,HISTID#23L,... 6 more fields] JDBCRelation([HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS]) [numPartitions=1]
                                    +- SubqueryAlias o
                                       +- SubqueryAlias customer_address
                                          +- Relation[CUSTADDRESSID#61L,ACCOUNTNO#62L,ADDRESSTYPE#63,ADDRESSLINE1#64,ADDRESSLINE2#65,ADDRESSLINE3#66,CITY#67,STATE#68,COUNTRY#69,ZIP1#70,ISACTIVE#71,ISCOMMUNICATION#72,CREATEDDATE#73,CREATEDUSER#74,UPDATEDDATE#75,UPDATEDUSER#76,REASONCODE#77,ZIP2#78] JDBCRelation([PLAY].TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES) [numPartitions=1]


18/08/07 13:31:26 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

If I success to get the result then I will be able to write the SparkSQL query to design the JSON in next query in Spark application, as @RameshMaharjan said.

Comment: You'd probably like to redact the emails and phone numbers

Comment: Can you please recheck @philantrovert

Comment: all you have to do is apply the same aggregation for email login and rest of the tables and use simple join. thats all you should get what you want

Comment: Ok lets try, But how a simple JOIN will work over here because the existing query contains collect_set and struct functions

Comment: for simplicity you will have to register each of the aggregated tables and use those newly registered tables in the join. Hope it helps

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Please check the updated part below in my question.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I think the error is coming from Query2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it and the credit goes to @Ramesh Maharajan because he advised me the approach in comment, I have implemented and I am showing below some code snippet descriptions which is showing that how I have achieved successfully.

```
  val db = "databasename"
  val table1 = "[HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS]"
  val custinfo1 = "[confidential].TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES"
  val custinfo2 = "[confidential].TP_CUSTOMER_BUSINESS"
  val custinfo3 = "[confidential].TP_CUSTOMER_EMAILS"
  val custinfo4 = "[confidential].TP_CUSTOMER_LOGINS"
  val custinfo5 = "[confidential].TP_CUSTOMER_PHONES"
```

I have registered the Master table and each customer information tables and joined one with each other, so I have used LEFT OUTER

So, the first join query I have written:

```
val query1 = "WITH RowNumberedAccounts AS(select  O.CUSTADDRESSID ,O.ADDRESSTYPE ,O.ADDRESSLINE1 ,O.ADDRESSLINE2 ,O.ADDRESSLINE3 ,O.CITY,O.STATE  ,O.COUNTRY  ,O.ZIP1  ,O.ISACTIVE  ,O.ISCOMMUNICATION  ,O.CREATEDDATE  ,O.CREATEDUSER  ,O.UPDATEDDATE  ,O.UPDATEDUSER  ,O.REASONCODE ,O.ZIP2   ,C.ACCOUNTNO         as C_ACCNO        ,C.CUSTOMERID        ,C.ACCOUNTGROUPID        ,C.PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID        ,C.PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE        ,C.SOURCEOFENTRY        ,C.REVENUECATEGORYID        ,C.VEHICLENUMBER        ,C.VEHICLECLASS        ,C.SERIALNO        ,C.HEXTAGID        ,C.TAGSTATUS        ,C.TAGSTARTEFFDATE        ,C.TAGENDEFFDATE        ,C.ISTAGBLACKLISTED        ,C.ISBLACKLISTHOLD        ,C.RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS        ,C.EMAILADDRESS        ,C.PHONENUMBER        ,C.CREATEDDATE AS CCreatedDate  ,C.CREATEDUSER AS CCreatedUser        ,C.UPDATEDDATE AS CUpdatedDate        ,C.UPDATEDUSER AS CUpdatedUser        ,C.HISTID        ,C.ACTION        ,C.ISFEEWAIVER        ,C.FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE        ,C.VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS        ,C.TAGTID        ,C.ISREVENUERECHARGE        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (            PARTITION BY C.VEHICLENUMBER            ORDER BY C.TAGSTARTEFFDATE DESC) AS rn    from        customer_account c        LEFT join customer_address o on c.ACCOUNTNO = o.ACCOUNTNO)SELECT    R.* FROM    RowNumberedAccounts AS R WHERE    rn = 1 order by C_ACCNO"
```

After that I have joined one with another,
And the **FINAL QUERY** of SparkSQL is:

```
val queryF = "SELECT C_ACCNO AS ACCOUNTNO, collect_set(struct(VEHICLENUMBER, CUSTOMERID,ACCOUNTGROUPID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE,SOURCEOFENTRY,REVENUECATEGORYID,VEHICLECLASS,SERIALNO,HEXTAGID,TAGSTATUS,TAGSTARTEFFDATE,TAGENDEFFDATE,ISTAGBLACKLISTED,ISBLACKLISTHOLD,RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS,EMAILADDRESS,PHONENUMBER,ISFEEWAIVER,FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE,VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS,TAGTID,ISREVENUERECHARGE,CCreatedDate,CCreatedUser,CUpdatedDate,CUpdatedUser)) as VEHICLE, collect_set(struct(CUSTADDRESSID ,ADDRESSTYPE ,ADDRESSLINE1 ,ADDRESSLINE2 ,ADDRESSLINE3 ,CITY,STATE  ,COUNTRY  ,ZIP1  ,ISACTIVE  ,ISCOMMUNICATION  ,CREATEDDATE  ,CREATEDUSER  ,UPDATEDDATE  ,UPDATEDUSER  ,REASONCODE ,ZIP2)) as ADDRESS, collect_set(struct(ORGANISATIONNAME,DATEOFINCORPORATION,PANCARDNUMBER,ORGANIZATIONTYPEID)) as BUSINESS, collect_set(struct(CUSTMAILID,EMAILTYPE,EMAIL,ISACTIVE_EMAIL,ISCOMMUNICATION_EMAIL)) as EMAIL, collect_set(struct(LOGINID,    USERNAME,   PASSWORD,   LAST_LOGINDATE, LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE,  CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE, PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT, PINNUMBER,  ISLOCKED,THEMES,LANGUAGES,  STATUSID,   USERTYPEID, ROLENAME,   SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT,    SQ_LOCKOUTTIME)) as LOGIN, collect_set(struct(CUSTPHONEID,  PHONETYPE, PHONENUMBER_PHONES,  EXTENTION, ISACTIVE_PHONES, ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES)) as PHONES FROM joined_acc_phones GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO"
     val res0F = sqlContext.sql(queryF.toString)
     res0F.show(10)
     res0F.coalesce(1).write.json("D:/result01")
```